# Ubuntu 17.10./16.04. Black Screen after Hibernation

Tags: 16.04, 17.10, hibernate

After hibernation my 16.04. Laptop shows me a blackscreen. I assume the keyboard is still responsive, because the back-lits on my keyboard worked.

I then upgraded from 16.04. to 17.10. and hoped the issue would be resolved. Unfortunately I still got a black screen after hibernation

`uname -r`
returns me this: 
`4.13.0-31-generic`

Answer (score 2):

There's [currently an open bug on Launchpad (#1743094)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743094) with waking from hibernation with a black screen for more recent kernels, including 4.13.0-31. You may want to subscribe to this bug to monitor progress.

The bug report does indicate success with installing a more recent kernel, (4.14.13-041413 is referenced).